# Order the child

Tags: judges

Can someone explain to me what does "order the child" mean? The context is the story of Manoah and his future son, Samson. Manoah asks the angel "How shall we order the child, and how shall we do unto him? [Judges 13](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Judges-Chapter-13/), verse 12)

Comment: Here, “order” means “bring up; grow; raise”.

Answer (score 5):

The KJV translation of Judges 13:12 is a little foreign to modern ears. Here is a sampling of more modern versions that translate the Hebrew well.

- NIV:  So Manoah asked him, “When your words are fulfilled, what is to be the rule that governs the boy’s life and work?”
- ESV: And Manoah said, “Now when your words come true, what is to be the child’s manner of life, and what is his mission?”
- BSB: Then Manoah asked, “When your words come to pass, what will be the boy’s rule of life and mission?”
- NKJV: Manoah said, “Now let Your words come to pass! What will be the boy’s rule of life, and his work?”
- NASB: Then Manoah said, “Now when your words are fulfilled, what shall be the boy’s way of life and his vocation?”

Benson's comments are also helpful:

> **Jdg 13:12**. Now let thy words come to pass — Or, thy words shall come to pass. I firmly believe thy promises shall be fulfilled. How
> shall we order the child? — Houbigant renders this, What shall be the
> method of educating the child? What rules shall we observe in bringing
> him up? How shall we do unto him? — What profession shall we prepare
> him for, or how shall we instruct him, so as to make him fit to be the
> deliverer of Israel?

Comment: +1 JPS: 12Then Manoah said, “May your words soon come true! What rules shall be observed for the boy?”